# How to render a part of Component A in Component B

Tags: angular, ng-template, ng-content

I have a component `A` and `B`

```
<div class="A">
    <div class="A1"></div>
    <div class="A2"></div>
</div>

<div class="B">
    <!--want to display <div class="A1"></div> here-->
</div>
```

Component `B` does not contain component `A` or way around

```
<componentA></componentA>
<componentB></componentB>
```

I tried to wrap `<div class="A1"></div>` in to `ng-template` and then in `componentB` I was querying for that, but it is always `undefined`:

`@ViewChild('templ') templ: TemplateRef<any>;`

Then I realized that `@ViewChild` is to query component children, so how would you query and render `<ng-template>` it it is not child component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look in to this [awesome sideNav sample](http://stackblitz.com/edit/adv-ng-left-nav) by Alex Rickabaugh, that demoing exactly what you need.

Based on that you need to define an `ng-container` in your `ComponentA`. Then you need to mark the piece of your `ComponentB` with a custom directive and there is a service that connecting `ComponentA` and `ComponentB`:

```
<div class="A1"><div>
<div class="A2" *leftNav >
  <h3>Content</h3>
</div>
```

Directive:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[leftNav]',
})
export class LeftNavDirective implements OnInit {
  constructor(private leftNav: LeftNav, private ref: TemplateRef<any>) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.leftNav.setContents(this.ref);
  }
}
```

Service:

```
@Injectable()
export class LeftNav {
  private _state = new BehaviorSubject<TemplateRef<any>|null>(null);
  readonly contents = this._state.asObservable();

  setContents(ref: TemplateRef<any>): void {
    this._state.next(ref);
  }

  clearContents(): void {
    this._state.next(null);
  }
}
```

Finally in your `ComponentB` you have to subscribe for your `<div class="A1"> ... <div>` thing on `ngAfterViewInit`:

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this
      .leftNav
      .contents
      .subscribe(ref => {
        if (this._current !== null) {
          this._current.destroy();
          this._current = null;
        }
        if (ref === null) {
          return;
        }
        this._current = this.vcr.createEmbeddedView(ref);
    });
  }
```

P.S there is a [video](http://Advanced%20Angular%20Concepts) and [slides](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1o1zbqxe-Fn4IdGRYeVGFNQb1PSiOpjXvIsNHRC7Bk1w) available on that topic.

Answer (score 2):

Render component `A`'s template as content of component `B`

```
<ComponentB>
   <ComponentA></ComponentA>
</ComponentB>
```

Inside template of `componentB` render 'content' (in this case `ComponentA`'s template)

`ComponentB.component.html`

```
<ng-content> </ng-content>
```

To get access to rendered `ComponentA` in `ComponentB` use `ContentChild`

```
@ContentChild(ComponentA) footer: componentA;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create common `ng-template` in parent component and pass its `templateRef` to child component in `Input` bindings of component. Later the inner component will fill in the template bindings for that template.

What that means is add `@Input a1: TemplateRef<any>;` inside both the component and lets put below `ng-template` in parent component of component A's & B's parent(basically they have same parent).

```
<ng-template #a1>
    <div class="A1">
       {{item.Description}}
    </div>
</ng-tmeplate>
```

**Component A template**

```
<div class="A">
    <ng-container 
       *ngTemplateOutlet="a1;context:{item: valueFromComponentA}">
    </ng-container>
    <div class="A2"></div>
</div>
```

**Component B temlpate**

```
<div class="B">
    <ng-container 
       *ngTemplateOutlet="a1;context:{item: valueFromComponentB}">
    </ng-container>
</div>
```